# Automount disk connected through USB when the PC is turned on

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, automounting, usb-device

I have a PC with Linux Mint 18 XFCE with an external drive permanently connected through USB. I never disconnect it.

When I turn on my PC, the disk is recognized but it is not mounted. I have to "manually" mount it. Actually I just have to click on its icon in Nemo to mount it.

But I'd like to have it automatically mounted so it is always available.

How can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly *never* disconnect it, then you could have it mounted at boot along with your system partitions (/, /home, ...). This is done in `/etc/fstab`.

Assuming the partition you want to mount automatically is `/dev/sdb1`, run the following in order to get the partition's UUID:

```
# blkid /dev/sdb1 -s UUID -o value
```

Then, given the `<UUID>` string you just got, and `/mnt/usb` as your target mount point, append the following line to `/etc/fstab` :

```
UUID=<UUID>    /mnt/usb    ext4       defaults    0    2
```

or, for NTFS instead of `ext4` :

```
UUID=<UUID>    /mnt/usb    ntfs-3g    rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137    0    2
```

Where `1000` and `1000` are your user's UID and GID ; otherwise the device will be mounted with `root` ownership. The other options should be adjusted according to your needs.

Note that for `ntfs-3g`, you might have to install the `ntfsprogs` or `ntfs-3g` package, depending on your distribution.

**Edit :** if you think the device may not *always* be connected at boot time, I would suggest using the `nofail` option (which basically tells the system "don't make a fuss is it doesn't work"). This means that, in the above line, `defaults` becomes:

```
defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=10
```

For NTFS, adding these options (starting from `nofail`) after `rw` should do it.

I've also added `x-systemd.device-timeout` which a systemd parameter telling the boot sequence to wait 10s before giving up on the device. If you don't specify this option, the default waiting time is 90s. Setting it to zero will make the system wait forever (your booting sequence will hang).

As for your other point: disconnecting the disk when the PC is on isn't a big deal, since `fstab` is a boot sequence thing. However, disconnecting a mounted device has its risks, since I/O operations are postponed through the use of caches, and your data may not have been synced on disk by the time you pull the plug. If you call `umount` (or use your graphical interface to un-mount) before disconnecting, then you're good. Calling `sync` instead is probably good enough, but more hazardous.

Comment: Thank you. It is not that i _never_ ever disconnect it... but it might happen maybe once per month... I mean, it is always connected to my PC but it is an external drive that I can use to move data to other computers. Based on you answer and the emphasis you did on the word _never_ I'm not sure if it is safe to implement your solution. What could happen if I disconnect the disk with the PC turned on? Or what could happen if I turn on the PC and the disk is not there? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @juankvillegas I've edited my answer. The first case requires adjustements, the second not really.

Comment: Thank you @JohnWHSmith. But... the blkid command do not show anything.

Comment: and... it is formatted as ntfs.

Comment: `blkid` should be run as root or with `sudo` (a `#` prompt usually means `root`). I've edited my answer to include an NTFS example. You'll find more information on the [`ntfs-3g`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g) and [`fstab`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) man pages. Remember to add such details to your questions :-p